# A resized dialog is not showing scroll bars if the resolution is too small

Tags: mfc, modal-dialog, resize, scrollbar

I am confused about a certain issue to do with my dialog. It is a re-sizeable dialog and uses the modern dynamic layout properties for managing control positions.

Yesterday I was doing a test on a IBM ThinkPad running Windows 10 (several years old but with a freshly installed operating system) and when I tried my program the dialog looked like this:

[image: Screen Grab]

What surprised me is that no scroll bars are visible. This means it is impossible for me or a potential user to navigate down / across to other controls on the window.

Obviously i don't want placeholders for scroll bars on the screen all the times because that would be ugly. So I only want scroll bars if and when they are needed. This is the resolution of the laptop:

[image: Screen Resolution]

Are there resource settings and / or a combination of coding in `OnCreate` or `OnInitDialog` to managed this issue?

## Update

At the moment the scroll bar controls are set to false in the resources:

[image: Resource Properties]

As mentioned above, that is how I want it by default. We should only have scrollbars there if needed. I am surprised that the dynamic layout mechanism does not handle this as standard.

I welcome your comments.

Comment: AFAIK this is something supported only by the "view" classes like `CScrollView` and the derived `CFormView`. For dialog-based apps you have to implement scrolling yourself.

Comment: @zett42 Is there a good resource you can recommend? Ideally something generic that I could add to my base `CResizingDialog` class?

Comment: Maybe this [codeproject article](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/10902/add-scrolling-to-a-cwnd-or-cdialog-using-a-c-helpe) helps. You also have to think about, what should happen when the user navigates through the dialog using keyboard. You would like to scroll the focused control into view, if necessary. I don't know if the code provided by this article takes care of that.

Comment: Just had a quick look at the source from the CP article. From a first glance, it doesn't look like they do it completely wrong, but the keyboard navigation (scroll focused control into view) isn't considered by the code. BTW, to build the code with VS2017, I had to change "Windows SDK version" in project settings > "Generic" to the latest "10.x.x.x" version available from the drop-down list

Comment: @zett42 I tried to use some of the code but this won't compile `DLGTEMPLATEEX* newTemplate = (DLGTEMPLATEEX*)LockResource(hDialogTemplate);`

Comment: @zett42 I was trying the code in the comments that says you should get able to get the size from dialog resources. I am trying to put this code in my based resize class you see so the dimension can't be hard coded.

Comment: @zett42 Looks like I needed : `_DialogSplitHelper::DLGTEMPLATEEX* newTemplate = (_DialogSplitHelper::DLGTEMPLATEEX*)LockResource(hDialogTemplate);`

Comment: Can't use it. Plays havoc with my dynamic layouts.

Comment: We seem to have a fight here.  OnGetMinMaxInfo is used to stop the window being resized smaller than default. So dynamic layout works. But if we want scroll bars it is because we have resized smaller, but, if resizing smaller than the default then no dynamic layout should be happening. It just gets messy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183152/discussion-between-zett42-and-andrew-truckle).